# ¿Como uso variables primitivas en parametros de tipo generico?

Tags: java, variables, objeto

```
public class Variant<X>
{
    private X value;

    //constructors
    public Variant(final X value)
    {
        setValue(value);
    }

    //setters
    public void setValue(final X newValue)
    {
        value = newValue;
    }

    //getters
    public X getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //¿Como evito usar Integer aqui?
        Variant<Integer> x = new Variant<Integer>(2);
    
        System.out.println(x.getValue());
    }
}
```

Esta clase esta pensada para poder almacenar cualquier tipo de dato pero segun he leido por ahi las clases que encapsulan los tipos primitivos cuestan mucha memoria y procesador
Necesito que esta clase sea lo mas eficiente posible ¿Hay manera de utilizarla con variables primitivas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Java, el tipo de cualquier variable es un tipo primitivo o un tipo de referencia. Los argumentos de tipo genérico deben ser tipos de referencia. Dado que los primitivos no extienden de Object, no se pueden usar como argumentos de tipo genérico para un tipo parametrizado.

No deberías preocuparte por eso. Eso de costar mucha memoria y procesador es cierto, pero si se compara con un tipo primitivo. Pero en la práctica esa diferencia es tan pequeña que es imperceptible.

Más que buscar la efiencia de la clase, la eficiencia del programa en general depende del uso de los algoritmos y estructuras de datos correctas.

Respondiendo a tu pregunta: No, no se puede.

Comment: ok, preguntaba si existia algun truco con el que pudiera "palear" el no poder hacerlo... pero bueno, seguire con el programa y vere como sale... Gracias!